# How to use Content-Type-multipart/form-data; boundary= ------WebKitFormBoundaryQoBY2Xgnc8K2sTzQ request for file upload in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using POST request which uses Content-Type as "multipart/form-data; boundary= ------WebKitFormBoundaryQoBY2Xgnc8K2sTzQ".

Under Parameters Tab:
Parameter Name:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQoBY2Xgnc8K2sTzQ
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name
```

Value:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQoBY2Xgnc8K2sTzQ
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fakeupload"
 
 C:\fakepath\software-development-life-cycle-planning.jpg

------WebKitFormBoundaryQoBY2Xgnc8K2sTzQ
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="software-development-life-cycle-planning.jpg"
 Content-Type: image/jpeg
 
 
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryQoBY2Xgnc8K2sTzQ--
```

I have selected use multipart/form-data checkbox. Response is 500 Internal server error. How to handle this request.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're not certain regarding how to properly build a file upload request I would recommend just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. If you're using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol - import `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` into your browser, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation entry for more details
3. Copy the file you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, see [Recording File Uploads](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) with JMeter article for more details
4. Upload the file in browser
5. JMeter will capture the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

---

If you want to continue with the manual setup - remove [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header from the HTTP Header manager and everything from "Body Data" tab of the HTTP Request sampler. In the "Files Upload" tab provide relative or absolute path to the file, HTML input name and MIME type. And of course tick `Use multipart/form-data` box

Comment: I used blazemeter to record the script and exported to jmeter. This request is a form sumbission with number of values with file upload. Kindly suggest on how to handle this request with ``------WebKitFormBoundaryQoBY2Xgnc8K2sTzQ``